# How to count filtered data in array by Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-repeat` with search filter:

```
 <div class="user-item item" ng-repeat="(key, itm) in filtered = (app | filter:searchInside | orderObjectBy:'id':true | groupBy: 'date_title') track by $index">
```

When I pass word in input field with `ng-model="searchInside"` I get filtered items in `filtered`.

But when I do `{{filtered.length}}` I get nothing always.

How I can count filtered data?

Comment: Could you provide code snippets illustrating your issue?

Comment: Need to show how you create `filtered` ... we have no idea where or how you are doing it

Comment: I proviede my code with ng-repeat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the results to a new variable (e.g. filtered) and access it:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in filtered = (data | filter: query)">
</div>
```

Display the number of results:

```
Showing {{filtered.length}} Persons
```

[see the similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/Nk8qy/3/)

Comment: Sorry I missed one part of my code. Now there is that

Comment: Is it helped you or not? if yes, marked it answer so it can help other in future

Comment: No it does not work for me. May be filter does not work with groupBy?